# Equalize the height of left and right div, prevent right div from going below left div

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML page with content divided into left and right part using `CSS`. The height of left content in smaller than the right content. Hence the right content div goes below to the left content div also. Eventually the border of right content is not a straight line.

1. How can we avoid the creeping of the right content towards the left?
2. How can we make the height of left content increased till the height of right content (with javascript)?

[image]

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .myContent {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .myHeader {
        }

        .leftPart {
            border: 1px solid blue;
            width: 200px;
            clear: left;
            float: left;
            background-color: red;
        }

        .rightPart {
            border: 1px solid orange;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: beige;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <div class="myHeader">
            H
        </div>
    </header>

    <div id="body">
        <div class="myContent">

            <div class="leftPart">
                A
            </div>
            <div class="rightPart">
                <div >
                    <label for="Sales_and_Marketing">Sales and Marketing</label>
                    <input id="SalesAndMarketing" name="SalesAndMarketing" type="text" value="" />
                </div>
                 <div >
                    <label for="Sales_and_Marketing">Sales and Marketing</label>
                    <input id="Text1" name="SalesAndMarketing" type="text" value="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question, but can you try with `float: right` for the `.rightPart` and remove the `width`? Is this what you are looking for? If yes, I will make it an answer.

Answer (score 3):

`fLoat` one element, set `margin` to the other one.

```css
.leftPart {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}

.rightPart {
    margin-left: 200px;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    background-color: beige;
}
```

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/ezIf/1/edit)**

### Update #1

If you consider using JavaScript, you might want to take a look at **[`equalize.js`](https://github.com/tsvensen/equalize.js)**.

***equalize.js*** is a jQuery plugin for equalizing the `height` or `width` of HTML elements.

Here is an example:

```
// Equalize the height of div element children
$('.myContent').equalize({children: '> div'});
```

Here is the **[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/ezIf/2/edit)**.

### Update #2

If you're looking for a pure CSS solution, you can use `display: table-cell;` CSS declaration.

**But**, *honestly,* I'd prefer using JavaScript rather than *this*, because using table `display` types, may change behavior of web browser while rendering the page (browsers may consider the entire page as a table):

```css
#body { display: table; width: 100%; }

.myContent { display: table-row; }

.leftPart {
  width: 200px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.rightPart {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Here is the **[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/ezIf/5/edit)**

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how we can resolve the second part of the question?

Comment: Wrap it in a `div` and set the `.leftPart` `height:100%`

Answer (score 0):

Add this style:

```css
.rightPart {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```