# left and right col same height after dynamically inserted content

Tags: html, css

I have some html:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="leftCol"></div>
    <div id="rightCol"></div>
</div>
```

css like:

```
#content {    
    position:absolute;
    width:98%;
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-right:1%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
    padding:0;
}

#leftCol {
   position:absolute;
   min-height:100%;
   float:left;
   width:60%;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-top:1px solid #acacac;
   border-left:1px solid #dfdfdf;
   border-right:1px solid #dfdfdf;
}

#rightCol {
    float:right;
    width:40%;
    min-height:100%;
    border-right:1px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-top:1px solid #acacac;
}
```

When content is added to #leftCol the height 100% is only applied to the 100% when document is loaded. I have a system the dynamically inserts content into #rightContent.

I want to "syncronize" so #leftCol is same height #rightCol after insertion of content. Is this possible with pure css? I could of course use js to achieve this, but css would be nicer :-)

Comment: Seems ironic that you can't figure this out.. "bestprogrammerintheworld"!!

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18362090/1725764

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QNPSs/2/)

```
   #main {
        display: table;
        width: 500px;
    }
    #left, #right {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    #left {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
        width: 250px;
    }
    #right {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 green;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#content {    
    position:absolute;
    width:98%;
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-right:1%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
    padding:0;
    display: table;
}
#leftCol {
    display: table-cell;
    width:60%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top:1px solid #acacac;
    border-left:1px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-right:1px solid #dfdfdf;
}

#rightCol {
    display: table-cell;
    width:40%;
    min-height:100%;
    border-right:1px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-top:1px solid #acacac;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/8drRS/1/) with css and HTML. In your css file you are using id but in html you are adding class.

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }
#content {    
    width:98%;
    margin:1% 1%;
    padding:0;
    border:1px solid #999999;
    display:table;  
}

#leftCol {
   width:58%;
   padding:1%;
   background-color:#99FFCC;
   display:table-cell;
}

#rightCol {
    width:38%;
    padding:1%;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    display:table-cell;
}


<div id="content">
    <div id="leftCol">
        <p>Whether you're preparing a romantic valentine's dinner or having friends over to watch the big game, our meal planning guide can help.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="rightCol"><p>The right glass of wine or beer can turn a good meal into a great one. Let us help you take the mystery out of beer and wine shopping.</p></div>
</div>
```