# Side nav full height 100%

Tags: html, css, navigation, sidebar

I am trying to get a side nav to be full height of the container.

This is how it is set up at the moment

HTML:

```
<div class="contentPage">
    <div class="nine columns"></div>
    <div class="three columns sideNav"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.contentPage{
  background: white;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  width: 960px;
}  

.nine{
  width:75%;
}

.three{
  width:25%;
}

.sideNav{
  top: -20px;
  left: 12px;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

This doesn't make the sideNav go full height, but also I don't want to set a height to my contentPage because it needs to vary depending of the amount of content in.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18362090/1725764

Comment: @HashemQolami It does indeed ! It works !
Please add your commend as an answer.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help

Comment: I don't know which one of those approaches worked for you. But if you found it helpful, you could upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for.  This takes care of your padding around so it is full height and i tested it on chrome, fire fox, and ie11.

```
<style>
.contentPage{
    background: white;
    width: 960px;
}

.nine{
    width:75%;
}

.three{
    width:25%;
}

.sideNav{
    top: -20px;
    left: 12px;
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;

}</style>

<div class="contentPage">
    <div class="nine columns">
    </div>

    <div class="three columns sideNav">
    </div>
</div>
```