# Wrapper Does not appear fully to the footer

Tags: html, css

I made a simple layout consisting of wrapper, header, main, sidebar and footer. Everything works normally except the wrapper, the height of a wrapper does not reach the footer element. I tried changing the high value, trying to use clearfix but there were no changes at all, here's a picture of the problem (I rounded it up)

[Sample image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic5cd.png)

This is the code :

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 background-color: blue;
}
.header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: red;
}
.main {
 width: 800px;
 height: 100%;
 margin-right: 20px;
 background-color: yellow;
 float: left;
}
.sidebar {
 width: 180px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: green;
 float: left;
}
.footer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Hello World !</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
  <meta charset='UTF-8' />
</head>
<body>
<div class='wrapper'>
 <div class='header'>Header</div>
 <div class='main'>Main</div>
 <div class='sidebar'>Sidebar</div>
 <div style='clear:both;'></div>
 <div class='footer'>Footer</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So why doesn't the height of a wrapper reach the footer element? and how to overcome it?

Comment: Could this be the answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21435207/4813913

Comment: I don't think so, because the problem lies in the parent element (wrapper) that doesn't reach the end of the browser height (100%) or reaches the footer element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pixels (px) are referred to as absolute units because they will always be the same size regardless of any other related settings. The percentage is often used to define a size as relative to an element's parent object.

Here the parent element is identified by wrapper class and the main being its child class, is taking all the height of wrapper. So to amend, make all the child classes' height in percentage.

Answer (score 0):

because you gave your .header and .footer height 40px and at the same time gave .main and .sidebar height 100% that caused the problem.
so instead of giving .header and .footer height 40px give them height in percent like .header height 10% and .footer height 10% and both .main and  .sidebar height 80% so the total height 100% and that will solve the problem.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 background-color: blue;
}
.header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 10%;
 background-color: red;
}
.main {
 width: 800px;
 height: 80%;
 margin-right: 20px;
 background-color: yellow;
 float: left;
}
.sidebar {
 width: 180px;
 height: 80%;
 background-color: green;
 float: left;
}
.footer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 10%;
 background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Hello World !</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
  <meta charset='UTF-8' />
</head>
<body>
<div class='wrapper'>
 <div class='header'>Header</div>
 <div class='main'>Main</div>
 <div class='sidebar'>Sidebar</div>
 <div style='clear:both;'></div>
 <div class='footer'>Footer</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But is there another way that I can use px? and the height of the main and the header is still 100%? (So it's like a browser automatically calculates) so that the height of the wrapper does not exceed or less than.

Comment: you mean .main and .sidebar. put both of them in a separate wrapper and give them height 100%