# Increase container's height to the hightest element when with float: left, and float: right

Tags: html, css

I have a container element and two sub elements in it placed in as float: left, and float: right. The left-floated element has one line of text. The right-floated element has two lines separated by 
. Now, when this is deployed, the container takes up on the height of the left-floated element, so the second line in the right-floated element appears outside the container. What can we do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equalize the height of left and right div, prevent right div from going below left div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362026/equalize-the-height-of-left-and-right-div-prevent-right-div-from-going-below-le)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What all you need is to have a display: inline-block; or overflow: hidden; property in the container. Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8ngH/)

```
<div id="m">
    <div class="a">a<br>c</div>
    <div class="b">b</div>
</div>

#m{
    background-color: gray;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.a{
    float: left;
}

.a{
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a clearfix implementation. That fix is usually attached by a class name to the parent DIV that you want to expand to contain floated child elements. For example see http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html