# How to make gutter between columns in a CSS grid system

Tags: html, css, grid, grid-system

Does anyone know how to make a `20px` or `1em` gutter for the grid system below?

I got all the `div`s to all go in a row but I want to know how to add a gutter in between each div. I'm doing this to learn how grids are made. [jsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xc79h/1/).

```css
body {
    font:20px/1.2 Verdana, Arial; padding:0px; margin:0px;
}

*, *:after, *:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.row { width:100%; }

.row > [class*='col-'] { /* ... */ }
.row > [class*='col-']:last-of-type { /* ... */ }

[class*="col-"] {
    float:left; 
    height:200px;
    background-color: #dedede;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding-right:20px;
}

[class*=col-]:last-of-type {
    padding-right:0px;
}

.col-1-12 {
    width: calc(100% / 12);
}

.col-2-12 {
    width: calc(100% / 12 * 2);
}

.col-3-12 {
    width: calc(100% / 12 * 3);
}
.col-4-12 {
    width: calc(100% / 12 * 4);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4-12">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
    <div class="col-2-12">
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
    </div>      
    <div class="col-3-12">
        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>  
    <div class="col-3-12">
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to have spacing between each div of 20px except for the first on the left side and the last div on the right

Comment: actually it would be good if all had spacing of 20px instead so it will look correct on the page

Comment: this is what I kinda want but it has margin of 10px on the left and right of the first and last divs which i want to have 20px, i have also updated my col-1-6* with a different calculation. what I want is to have 20px between each side. http://jsfiddle.net/xc79h/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here is the calculation of the columns' width, base on the column number considering the gutter of `20px` between each column.

For instance, `col-2-12`:

```css
width: calc( (100% - (12/2 - 1) * 20px) / 12 * 2 );
```

Explanation:

```css
width:
    (100%   /* Total width */
      - (12/2 - 1) * 20px /* Number of gutters between col-2  x  gutter width */
    ) / 12 /* Total columns */
      * 2  /* Size of the current column which is col-2 */
```

Also, instead of using `margin` for the first and the last column, you can use `padding` for the container `.row` and set the `margin` for that columns to `0`.

In addition, as the columns are floated, you should clear the float at the bottom of the `.row` element.

```css
.row {
    padding: 0 20px;
    *zoom: 1;
}

.row:after, .row:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: table;
}

.row:after { clear: both;}

.row > [class*='col-']:first-child { margin-left: 0; }
.row > [class*='col-']:last-child { margin-right: 0; }
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/xc79h/5/)**.

## Sassy CSS

Using CSS preprocessors such as **[Sass](http://sass-lang.com/)**, makes the calculation of grid systems fun!

Here is the Sassy way of a **fluid grid system**:

```css
$total_columns : 12;
$total_width   : 100%;
$gutter_width  : 2%;

.row {
    padding: 0 $gutter_width;
    *zoom: 1;

    &:after, &:before { content: ' '; display: table; }
    &:after { clear: both; }

    & > [class*='col-']:first-child { margin-left: 0; }
    & > [class*='col-']:last-child { margin-right: 0; }
    & > [class*='col-'] { margin: 0 $gutter_width/2; }
}

[class*="col-"] {
    float:left; min-height:200px;
    background-color: #dedede; border: 1px solid #000;
}

@for $i from 1 through $total_columns {
    .col-#{$i}-#{$total_columns} {
        width: (100% - ($total_columns/$i - 1) * $gutter_width) / $total_columns * $i;
    }
}
```

**[ONLINE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/9za3k/)**.

Comment: can you make another example by the way for the gutter on the left and right to not have margin of 20px so only the ones between the first and last div's have margin

Comment: @KDM Of course! however you can simply remove `padding: 0 20px` declaration from `.row` element. That'll do the trick ;) Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/xc79h/6/

Comment: My other question is that the text overflows because the height is set so if I don't set the height how do you have all the elements(divs) have the same height based on the div that is the highest in since it has more content.

Comment: @KDM Since we use `float` property for the columns, We can't. The only pure CSS way is using `table-cell` display types which I highly recommend to **avoid** using them for grid/layout purposes. But If you consider using JavaScript you can use [equalize.js](http://tsvensen.github.io/equalize.js/). For further info you can refer my **[answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362026/equalize-the-height-of-left-and-right-div-prevent-right-div-from-going-below-le/18362090#18362090)**.

Comment: I have another interesting question which I've wanted to know. How do you collapse the div's when they reach a certain width like an ipad size or iphone size

Comment: @KDM Well, as a pure CSS solution you can use [`@media` queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to declare some break points and apply the specific CSS rules to the elements in that different situations, as the [modern CSS framewokrs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries) do. I also suggest to take a look at [Chris Coyier's article](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)