# Elegant way to set the height of element to 100%

Tags: css, height

I search for a solution to set the height of an container to 100%

As I learned at [this site](http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm) all parent elements of the container has to be set to 100%.

This is not so easy in a content management side with about 30 parent elements.

The concept of the html is like this: All elements in the wrapper need to be equal and use 100% of the height of the wrapper.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left" class="container">
    Test<br/>
    ....maybe more content
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="container">
    Test<br/>
    ....maybe much more content
  </div>
</div>
```

So I fiddled a little bit with a javascript solution.

I "calculate" the height of the biggest element an set it to the container class so all of them.

[The fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mattes/jryno01j/)

Do you think this is a elegant solution or is there a smarter way?

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Have a look at: [Equalize the height of left and right div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362026/equalize-the-height-of-left-and-right-div-prevent-right-div-from-going-below-le/18362090#18362090)

Comment: try position:absolute; of your wrapper without js your work will done.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```
var biggestHeight = $("#wrapper").height();
$("#wrapper").children().css("height",biggestHeight+"px");
```